# Getting errors while trying to create EC2 Instance using create_instances() function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, boto3

So I have created a security group with inbound traffic rule, keypair and am trying to create an instance using this code

```
instances=ec2.create_instances(ImageId="ami-d38a4ab1",MinCount=1,MaxCount=1, InstanceType="t2.micro",KeyName="my-key",SecurityGroupIds=['sg.##############'])
```

But I keep getting an error saying:

> An error occurred(invalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation:Value() for paramet groupID is invalid. The value cannot be empty.

I am unsure of what am I doing wrong.

Comment: the right format should be 'sg-#####' and not 'sg.#####', even though im not sure this is the actual issue.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code (without the Key and Security Group) and it worked perfectly find for me:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2_resource.create_instances(
    ImageId="ami-d38a4ab1",
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1, 
    InstanceType="t2.micro"
    )
```

The error message is saying that the Parameter Group ID is invalid, which suggests that you did now provide us with the *actual* command you are running.